# Do Scandavian pension systems have a minimum benefit? Are people who reach 70 without ever working entitled to benefits?

Tags: retirement

In the United States social security system, your benefits depend on your average earnings over some period. So people who never worked aren't entitled to any retirement benefits. How does the pension system in Scandinavia work? Can I expect any benefits from the state when I never worked?

Comment: If, at any time in your life, you think "every X works like in the US", you will be wrong :)

Comment: In Germany welfare would be responsible for providing you with enough income to live off of. They would also be making up the difference if your retirement benefits are lower than what welfare would be. I assume 'scandinavia (which is not a country, they likely have several similar but different systems depending on country)' has similar systems in place.